# How to print firebase document reference to screen using flutter

Tags: json, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know how to print a Firebase document reference to phone7tablet screen using flutter I have tried this so far:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(stream: stations,builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
                  if(snapshot.hasError){
                    return SnackBar(content: Text("Something went wrong"));
                  }
                  if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                    return SnackBar(content: Text("Loading"));
                  }
                  final data = snapshot.requireData;

                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: data.size,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index){
                      var ref = data.docs[index]["ref"].toString();
                      return Text(ref);

                    },
```

***Heres a screenshot of my database*:**
[image: Database screenshot]

To be more elaborate I want to print contents of the document that is being linked by "ref" variable.

inside the test collection there are two fields:

1. name (a string field)
2. age (an integer field)

***Heres my code output:***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ref` field seems to be a reference to another document. The linked document is not automatically loaded, but instead returned as a [`DocumentReference` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html).

To load the linked document, wrap it in a `FutureBuilder` and call `data.docs[index]["ref"].get()` as the future, as shown in the FlutterFire documentation on [reading a document once](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#one-time-read).